# Background color of tab does not change unless user clicks again after selecting tab

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a tab based page that looks like the following when loaded: 
[image]

After the page is loaded and the middle tab is selected, I get the following:[image]

When I click anywhere on the page after the tab is selected, I get this:[image]

I want the background color of the tab to be "pink" (#e12387) when selected. I am not sure why I have to click somewhere on the page for the color change to take place. This problem occurs when any of the tabs are selected.

Comment: Can you able to send the wordpress URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Just got to view the page on a computer. I have had this issue in the past when I use .active on some elements.

Try this...

```
li.nav-item a.nav-link.active:not(:active) {
    background: #e12387
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Tried what you said, but it didn't work for me. You can check the page: http://kvctech.com/about/ and see for yourself.

Comment: @hvasam I edited my answer. Try that css, it worked in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you out:

```
.pt-tabs ul li a{background-color:#000;color:#fff!important;text-decoration:none;}
.pt-tabs ul li a:active, .pt-tabs ul li a:focus{background-color:#e12387!important;text-decoration:none;}
.pt-tabs__content, .pt-tabs__content p{background-color:#e12387!important;}
```